How can I use with jetpack HorizontalPager with HorizontalPagerIndicator on NavHost controller
I have nine screens and I want use NavHost with HorizontalPagerIndicator.

Use HorizontalPager
 val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {
  10
 })

 HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
 // Our page content
 Text(
    text = "Page: $page",
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
}

for more details refer Pager in compose

NavHost with views must be inside HorizontalPager? Or I can't use NavHost with pager?

@Slava NavHost is used for multiple screen mappings and Pager are also used for same purpose so I clearly don't understand you POV for using NavHost inside Pager. As there are already multiple tabs to represent different screen in Pager.
